# Is there a way to pass a value into an Interceptor class?

Tags: angular, request, eventemitter

*For background*: I have an interceptor that clones a request and inserts a bearer token, I want to add another field to this `newRequest` called: `id` with a value I grabbed from an `eventEmitter` in another class: `AppComponent`

I have value but I can't pass it to the interceptor like I would to a component via html. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hi Gustas, I dont know details but it looks like you need to use local storage. Firstly set your item into local storage and then get it in the interceptor. take a look: https://blog.jscrambler.com/working-with-angular-local-storage/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! the local storage worked. Right now I'm trying to implement a service to grab the value so I can use it everywhere in my application.

Comment: you are welcome. turned it to an answer. Just check if it is work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know details but it looks like you need to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Firstly set your item into local/session storage and then get it, in the interceptor.
Please just consider for security precautions and search for which storage type is proper for you.

take a look:
[working-with-angular-local-storage](https://blog.jscrambler.com/working-with-angular-local-storage/)  and [storage types in angular](https://techspawn.com/localstorage-session-storage-or-cookies-in-angular)